# Какие еще есть времена выполнения операций кроме логарифмического и линейного?

Tags: java, функции, время

интересуют особенности каждого из них

Comment: На пальцах логарифмическое быстрее. А бывают какие угодно.

Comment: временная сложность ничего не говорит о том, быстрее алгоритм работает или медленее. она говорит о том, как время работы алгоритма растет при увеличении количества данных. например, для какой-то задачи может существовать алгоритм o(1) - и запуск его на любых данных будет занимать миллион лет. поэтому ваш вопрос не имеет особого смысла. он читается как "есть синяя деревянная палочка и красная. какая из них вкуснее?" :)

Comment: @PashaPash вкуснее красная, но надо есть синюю потому что именно ее одобряет избранный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Время выполнение операции может быть любым. И n^2, и !n^1000 и т.д. Оно не ограничено ничем.

В предыдущем вопрос я привел вам ссылку: http://bigocheatsheet.com/. На этой странице приведет `Big-O Complexity Chart` на котором изображены графики функций для разных Big-O. Чем быстрее растет график, тем медленнее работает программа. Соответственно это верно для всех Big-O.

PS. Не в обиду вам, но всё это преподаётся на 1-2 курсе любой технической специальности и что такое Big-O и как определить её для любого алгоритма и т.д.

Comment: я извиняюсь, но у меня гуманитарное образование, точнее философское(  по- этому я кое-что не понимаю, но хотелось бы уточнить)

Comment: @MukolaShorobura тогда возможно стоит прослушать курсы лекций по программированию от Berkley или других вузов, сейчас не проблема найти их в онлайне, очень многие вопросы отпадут.